# Grunt-webpack: How to force production mode without build server access?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gruntjs

I do not have access to the build server, I can only modify the files. So I can't add any flags to the grunt command. The build server seems to simply run "grunt". I have tried all sorts of configurations without success, suggested here and other sources.

From my understanding webpack should by default build a production build but perhaps it was introduced in later versions of webpack only or not supported by grunt-webpack?

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
const path = require('path');

const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/');
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');

module.exports = function config(grunt) {
  grunt.option("p"); // attempt to force a -p flag on webpack, doesn't work

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    webpack: {
      reactcatalog: {
        entry: ['core-js/fn/promise', 'core-js/fn/map', 'formdata-polyfill', 'whatwg-fetch', `${APP_DIR}/index.js`],
        output: {
          path: BUILD_DIR,
          filename: 'react-catalog.js',
        },
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        },
        module: {
          loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            include: APP_DIR,
            loader: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: APP_DIR,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
          },
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            include: APP_DIR,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          },
          {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader!react-svg-loader',
          }],
        },
        stats: {
          colors: true,
        },
        progress: false,
        failOnError: false,
      },
    },
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-webpack');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['webpack']);
};
```

**package.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "react-catalog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "ES based React catalog",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-proto-to-assign": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017-node7": "^0.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "breakpoint-sass": "^2.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "formdata-polyfill": "^3.0.10",
    "grunt-webpack": "^3.1.1",
    "loaders.css": "^0.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "npm-install": "0.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.3.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-image-gallery": "^0.8.8",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^4.6.0",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.1.4",
    "react-intl-universal": "^1.10.1",
    "react-md-spinner": "^0.2.5",
    "react-move": "^2.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.9",
    "react-skylight": "^0.5.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.2.5",
    "react-svg": "^2.2.18",
    "react-svg-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "react-svg-spinner": "^0.2.0",
    "react-tabs": "^2.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "run": "^1.4.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "sassimple": "^1.3.8",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "susy": "^3.0.5",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "8.0.1",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.49.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.2",
    "webpack-livereload-plugin": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack", // does not help to add a -p flag here as it doesn't seem to use this
    "webpack:watch": "webpack --watch"
  }
}
```

I have tried all sorts of things without any success.

```js
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        process: {
          env: {
            NODE_ENV: 'production'
          }
        }
      })
    ]
```

becomes:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/893783/44646081-34498c00-a9da-11e8-8bd1-66c70b8ba9f5.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured out the solution myself!

```js
const path = require('path');
++ const webpack = require('webpack');
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/');
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');

module.exports = function config(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    webpack: {
      reactcatalog: {
        // ...
        plugins: [
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            process: {
              env: {
                NODE_ENV: '"production"'
              }
            }
          }),
          new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ]
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: It's funny how it works actually, the react js has a check `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... }` is then converted by the plugin into `if ('production' === 'production') { ... }` which is always true, and then the uglyfyJsPlugin removes all unreachable code so it deletes everything related to development environment and only keeps the production code, also removing that if statement :)